# Palabra reservada "new" en interfaces c#

Tags: c#

Saludos,

He estado jugando con algunas cosas de AspNet identity tratando de desacoplar algunos componentes.

Cuando intento definir una interfaz que implementa otras interfaces (para este caso interfaces de AspNet Identity) me aparece un warning en visual studio que me dice que debo utilizar la palabra reservada "new" en cada miembro de la interfaz porque esta ocultando a un miembro de las interfaces que implementa mi interfaz.

Aunque el warning efectivamente se quita al agregar al principio de la definición de cada miembro en la interfaz, me gustaría saber el porque de este warning y de las implicaciones que puede tener utilizar el "new" al inicio de cada miembro en la definición de la interfaz.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrijanme de no estar en lo correcto.

Cuando implementas una interfaz en otra, la palabra `new` no es tan importante a no ser que sea necesario cambiar algo en esa parte.

Básicamente estas diciendo "Quiero que mi nueva interfaz sea como la otra, pero quiero cambiarle unas cosas"

Ejemplo:

```
public interface IElement
{
    string Nombre { get; set; } 
}

public interface IAnotherElement : IElement
{
    new string Nombre { get; } 
}
```

La definición de `IAnotherElement.Nombre` va a ocultar el comportamiento directo de `IElement.Nombre` por lo que solo vas a modificar lo que sucede. En el ejemplo anterior, ambas definiciones son válidas, sin embargo, el warning solo es una advertencia que te dice que *puede corromper el comportamiento* de la interfaz padre.

Usando el ejemplo anterior, si ocultas una propiedad, dicho elemento, no podrá ser heredado por clases que implementen esa propiedad:

```
public class Element : IElement
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; } // Todo bien.
}

public class AnotherElement : IAnotherElement
{
    new public string Nombre { get; } // Warning.
}
```

Notese el `new` en la implementación de la clase.

Pero si quitamos el `new`:

```
public class AnotherElement : IAnotherElement
{
    public string Nombre { get; } // Error de implementación.
}
```

El compilador te advierte que falta el operador `set` en la definición de la propiedad.

Espero que te haya ayudado, [aquí](https://dotnetfiddle.net/75sVOX) te dejo un fiddle para que veas!!

Comment: Muchas gracias @NaCi me quedo más claro con tu explicación y el fiddle. +1

Comment: ¡No hay de qué! En adición a esto, considera extender una interfaz sólo a la hora de volverla más genérica, porque en su defecto, las interfaces solo son modelos de como será tu objeto final y todos sus derivados.